# Filtering text file to get unique entries based on value in column 3

Tags: bash, sorting, filter

I know a bit of bash, but I am facing a problem to filter a file. I'll explain with an example :

**Given a text file like the following (file1):**

```
10.10.12 bib24 Avenger goodone
10.10.12 bib21 The_Dark_Knight_Rises betterone
10.10.12 bib53 Avenger goodone
10.10.12 bib35 Ice_Age wow
11.10.12 bib53 TheAmazingSpiderMan nice
11.10.12 bib54 TheAmazingSpiderMan nice
11.10.12 bib01 Avenger goodone
12.10.12 bib29 Avenger goodone
12.10.12 bib11 TheAmazingSpiderMan nice
12.10.12 bib03 Ice_Age wow
12.10.12 bib98 Ice_Age wow
14.10.12 bib12 Ice_Age wow
```

**This is the result I want (file2):**

```
10.10.12 bib24 Avenger goodone
10.10.12 bib21 The_Dark_Knight_Rises betterone
10.10.12 bib35 Ice_Age wow
11.10.12 bib53 TheAmazingSpiderMan nice
```

**So my question is :** which command do I use to get this result (file2) ? (i.e. first entry of a movie, and not taking into account columns/fields 1, 2, and 4).

I hope it's clear enough.

Comment: But "Avenger goodone" is there 5 times ?! oO

Comment: yes so what? see, it's at different times with different bib

Comment: Sorry, French frog have sometimes more difficulty to understand than people speaking English as mother tongue

Comment: What the matter with froggies? I like them :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk '!a[$3]++' file.txt
```

Results:

```
10.10.12 bib24 Avenger goodone
10.10.12 bib21 The_Dark_Knight_Rises betterone
10.10.12 bib35 Ice_Age wow
11.10.12 bib53 TheAmazingSpiderMan nice
```

Comment: It's working for me. I still need to process some more tests nowl

Answer (score 4):

Try doing is:

```
sort -u -k3 file.txt
```

**Output**:

```
10.10.12 bib24 Avenger goodone
10.10.12 bib35 Ice_Age wow
11.10.12 bib53 TheAmazingSpiderMan nice
10.10.12 bib21 The_Dark_Knight_Rises betterone
```

Comment: It's not working, I still have some lines with the same movie.

Comment: Added output, It works as a charm for me. cut (GNU coreutils) 8.19

Answer (score 0):

For rusty csh users:

Use this:

```
awk '{c[$3]++} {if (c[$3] == 1) print $0}' file.txt
```

Because with original answer, it will error "event not found" (Can also make "!" normal character! but this is easier to read and use)